# Appending a part of the file name in the end of a line if a keyword is found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have set of files in a directory. File names are `abc-xyz-v01`, `abc-xyz-v02`, `abc-xyz,v03` and so on. In the file if there is a key word "`name`" present then I have to append the last part of the file name e.g. `v01` in that line.

This is the code that I have written and it's working fine, but is there any more elegant and better solution. I am new to bash scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash
# fileinfo.sh
FILES="/home/user/data/test/*"
for file in $FILES
do
echo "$file"
  x=0
  first=1
  linenum=$(awk '/name/{ print NR; exit }' $file)
  substr=$(echo $file | cut -d'-​' -f 3)
  cat $file | while read line; do
    x=$(( x+1 ))
    if [ $x -eq $first ]
      then echo $line > temp.txt
    elif [ $x -eq $linenum ]
      then echo $line-$substr >> temp.txt
    else
      echo $line >> temp.txt
    fi
  done
  mv temp.txt $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

for the file

```
$ cat abc-xyz-v01 

1
2
name
4
5
```

this will produce

```
$ awk '/name/{n=split(FILENAME,a,"-"); $0=$0 "-" a[n]}1' abc-xyz-v01 
1
2
name-v01
4
5
```

you can write your loop

```
$ for f in ...
  do awk ... "$f" > tmp && mv tmp "$f";
  ...
  done
```

Not sure what you want to do when there is no match, but easy to add an exit status to `awk` and condition on that.

Comment: It does not add the hyphen (-). Similar to this line in my code: `echo $line-$substr`

Comment: Same problem. Now only hyphen(-) gets appended.

Comment: are you sure the filenames are as you represented, there are two dashes?  If you want to get the last section check the update.

Comment: May be something to do with the gnu-awk installed on my ubuntu os. `$0=$0 "-" a[n]}1` does not translate to `name-v01` but only to `name-`

Answer (score 0):

With `gnu-awk`, it can be done in one singe command:

```
awk -i inplace '/name/{split(FILENAME, a, "-"); $0 = $0 "-" a[3]} 1' abc-xyz-v0{1..3}
```

Comment: filename is abc-xyz-v01. If this file has a word name present in it i want -v01 to be appended in that line. Like `name something-v01`. But this commands only give `name something-`

Comment: On my system when I run this command it outputs `name something-v01` as `a[3]` contains `v01` since we are splitting `abc-xyz-v01` on `-`